# Select records which have two digits on the left and four digits on the right side in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Table with example data:

```
ID   ANPR_TEXT
-------------
1    16AH22551 
2    DL8CM8797
```

In this example I' like to select the row with `16AH22551`.

I tried:

```
select ANPR_TEXT, 
       to_number(regexp_substr(ANPR_TEXT,'\d+$'))
  from TXN_SPEED_CAM;
```

But it didn't work. Could anyone help, please!

Comment: Please try this filter: `where regexp_like (anpr_text, '^\d{2}\w{0,}\d{4}$')`, worked for me.

Comment: @PonderStibbons: works like a charm! Could have been an answer ;) see Fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b7136c/2

Comment: @Trinimon - I know that it works, but was somewhat confused in OP's requests, so I don't know if it's what he wants, that's why I did not publish it as answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> I need 16AH22551

**Update** OP wants at least count to match, not exact match.

From documentation on [POSIX Metacharacters in Oracle Database Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm#CHDIEGEI)

> {m,}
>
> Interval—At Least Count
>
> Matches at least m occurrences of the preceding subexpression.
>
> The expression a{3,} matches the strings aaa and aaaa, but does not
>   match aa.

So, you need to use **{m, }** expression which means it will match at least m occurrences. `REGEXP_LIKE(anpr_text, '[[:digit:]]{2,}[[:alpha:]]{2,}[[:digit:]]{4,}')`

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(ID NUMBER, anpr_text VARCHAR2(20));

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES(1, '16AH22551');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES(2, 'DL8CM8797');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES(3, '123ABC8797 ');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES(4, 'HR29AE5806 ');

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM t
  2    WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(anpr_text, '[[:digit:]]{2,}[[:alpha:]]{2,}[[:digit:]]{4,}');

        ID ANPR_TEXT
---------- --------------------
         1 16AH22551
         3 123ABC8797
         4 HR29AE5806

SQL>
```

**For an exact pattern match:**

If you have a fixed pattern of first two digits, then two alphabets and then at least 4 digits, then you could do a **pattern match** using **REGEXP_LIKE**.

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(ID NUMBER, anpr_text VARCHAR2(20));

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES(1, '16AH22551');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES(2, 'DL8CM8797');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES(3, '123ABC8797');

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM t
  2  WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(anpr_text, '[[:digit:]]{2}[[:alpha:]]{2}[[:digit:]]{4}');

        ID ANPR_TEXT
---------- --------------------
         1 16AH22551

SQL>
```

Comment: Then your question is unclear. You need to explain the rules to get the desired output. You say, *select records based on which left side have 2 digit and right side have 4 digit in oracle* left side and right side of what?

Comment: in your example, i need 16AH22551 and 123ABC8797 records

Comment: @jayanta ok, see my updated answer. Please mark it as answered, it will help others.

Comment: can you match once--16AH20551 and HR29AE5806

Comment: @jayanta the updated answer is on the top. There is clearly mentioned in bold as **Update**

Comment: Look at the **Update** on the top. It completely answers your question, please mark it answered.